# jquery - regex string replacement for word before character

Tags: jquery, regex

### I asked this question before and I marked an answer but it only performed what I needed, partially.

I'm trying to select some text between 2 html tags. It should be pretty straight forward but I can't seem to figure it out.

HTML:

```
<article>
    width
    <span class="Punctuation">:</span> 
    80%
    <span class="Punctuation">;</span>
    height
    <span class="Punctuation">:</span> 
    80%
    <span class="Punctuation">;</span>
    background
    <span class="Punctuation">:</span> 
    grey
    <span class="Punctuation">;</span>
</article>
```

So I'm trying to select the word `Width` and the value, `80%` and store each in a different element.
The end result would be something like:

```
<article>
    <span class="Property">width</span>
    <span class="Punctuation">:</span> 
    <span class="Value">80%</span>
    <span class="Punctuation">;</span>
    <span class="Property">height</span>
    <span class="Punctuation">:</span> 
    <span class="Value">80%</span>
    <span class="Punctuation">;</span>
    <span class="Property">background</span>
    <span class="Punctuation">:</span> 
    <span class="Value">grey</span>
    <span class="Punctuation">;</span>
</article>
```

I can't use `.text()` because it selects ALL the plain text in the article that isn't in a `span` parent, while I'm trying to add `span` elements with different classes to it.

I'm basically looking for a regex way to select the word before the `:` character and wrap it in a `span` parent. Then I'd like to do the same with the `;` character.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

--- edit ---

I've tried some expressions but because I dont have any experience with regex and i find it very hard to wrap my head around, I haven't gotten very far.

I've tried to select the string starting with

```
var str = $('.code').html();
var match = str.match( /^: / );
alert(match);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

```
var str = $('.code').html();
var match = str.match( /;$/ );
alert(match);
```

Doesn't work either. Both return `null`

Comment: Before a downvote, please explain why

Comment: Show us your attempts you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Selects all the (naked text)
var nodetypes = $('article').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}), txt = nodetypes.text(); // store the naked text

nodetypes.remove(); // removed the naked text from the actual DOM

$.trim(txt.replace(/\n/g, '')) // remove all newlines from text
.replace(/\s+/g, ',')          // replaced one or more spaces with ","
.split(',')                    // split the string into array ','
.forEach(function (e, x) {     // loop through all the array items "e" is value "x" is index
    if (x % 2 === 0) {         // if x is even add element before `.Punctuation' class
        $('article .Punctuation').eq(x).before('<span class="Property">' + e + '</span>');
    } else {                   // if x is not even add element before `.Punctuation' class
        $('article .Punctuation').eq(x).before('<span class="Value">' + e + '</span>');
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bL8e/3/)

Comment: This seems to be working nicely! Can you explain what it does, exactly? :)

Comment: Thank you for the extra information :) Just another question though: if I want to insert the .Punctuation spans dynamically as well, how would I go about doing that with your answer?